# Service Fabric - IQueryable

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Do we support IQueryable to reliable collection?

Something like:

Task>IQueryable>InventoryItemView>> GetCustomerInventoryAsync(CancellationToken ct)

Answer (score 0):

No. Reliable collections do not support IQueryable today.